# コミット履歴を変更したmasterブランチに対してリベースしたい

Tags: git

以下のようなブランチで作業しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`bugfix1`ブランチでの作業が終わったので、`master`ブランチに取り込みます。
ただ、`bugfix1`のコミットは`master`ブランチの先頭コミットと１つにまとめたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし良い方法が思いつかず、以下のような無駄の多いであろう手順で行いました。
特にmasterブランチを一度削除している部分は「なんか違う」と感じます。

もっと短い手順で行う方法はありますでしょうか？

---

現在の状態は以下の通りとします。

```
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate

* 557ceac (HEAD -> bugfix1) C4
* 4c8dea5 (develop) C3
* fb1dc6b (master) C2
* 65947d3 C1
* e91df3b C0
```

手順1. C4の分岐元をC2に変更します。

```
git rebase --onto master develop bugfix1

* db81c6c (HEAD -> bugfix1) C4
| * 4c8dea5 (develop) C3
|/
* fb1dc6b (master) C2
* 65947d3 C1
* e91df3b C0
```

手順2. C3の分岐元をC4に変更します。

```
git rebase bugfix1 develop

* 2dd4032 (HEAD -> develop) C3
* db81c6c (bugfix1) C4
* fb1dc6b (master) C2
* 65947d3 C1
* e91df3b C0
```

手順3. masterブランチとbugfix1ブランチを削除します。

```
git branch -d master
git branch -d bugfix1

* 2dd4032 (HEAD -> develop) C3
* db81c6c C4
* fb1dc6b C2
* 65947d3 C1
* e91df3b C0
```

手順4. C2とC4を１つのコミットにまとめます。

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
（C2をreword、C4をfixup）

* f4bfc56 (HEAD -> develop) C3
* db88da9 C2+C4
* 65947d3 C1
* e91df3b C0
```

手順5. masterブランチを作ります。

```
git checkout db88
git branch master
git checkout develop

* f4bfc56 (HEAD -> develop) C3
* db88da9 (master) C2+C4
* 65947d3 C1
* e91df3b C0
```

---

追記

素直にやればよいことに気付きました。なにか混乱していたようです…。

```
git rebase --onto master develop bugfix1
git checkout master
git merge bugfix1
git branch -D bugfix1
git rebase -i HEAD~2
(C4をfixup）
git rebase master develop
```

Comment: bugfix1のコミット部分ですが、「bugfix1での一連の変更を取り込む = C3 + 4」と「bugfix1の C4 のみ取り込む」のどちらでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick masterブランチに取り込みたいのは「bugfix1のC4のみ取り込む」になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cherry-pick`を使用し、以下の手順で実行することで解決できそうです。

### 実行手順

#### 1. chery-pickでコミットを取り込む

`master`ブランチに切り替えた状態で、C4のコミットIDを指定して`cherry-pick`で取り込みます。元々のファイルの変更日時は維持されますが、コミットIDは新しいものになります。

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick 557ceac
```

#### 2. rebaseでコミットをまとめる

元々のmasterのコミット(C2)と、先ほど取り込んだコミット(C4')を`rebase`で1つにまとめます(最新2つ分のコミットが対象)。

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

指定した範囲のコミットIDとコミットメッセージの一覧がエディタで開いた状態になるので、変更しないコミットはそのまま(`pick`)、ファイルの変更は取り込むが履歴は削除するものはコミットIDを`fixup`に変更し、エディタを保存・終了します。

```
pick fb1dc6b C2
pick db88da9 C4'

# ↓以下のように変更
pick fb1dc6b C2
fixup db88da9 C4'
```

問題なければマージされ`master`に(C2+C4)を一つにまとめたコミット(C2')ができるはずです。

Comment: おっしゃる通り`cherry-pick`でも可能ですね。ちょっと混乱していたみたいです。ありがとうございます。